# I am new to React js and I am trying to create a project using it.while using map function, i am facing error

Tags: reactjs

I am creating  a website to deliver news.
I am beginner in reactJS and I am facing error:"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

I tried searching this online but was not able to understand what is wrong with this code.
Can somebody please help me?

Below is the code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NewsItem from "./NewsItem";

export class News extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("HELLO there");
    this.state = {
      articles: this.articles,
      loading: false,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This is a news component
          //This is the part which shows error
        {this.state.articles.map((element) => {
          console.log(element)
        })}
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-3">
            <NewsItem imageUrl="https://photos5.appleinsider.com/gallery/44585-86572-210921-macOSBigSur-xl.jpg" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default News;
```

Comment: `this.state.articles` is `this.articles` which doesn't seem to ever have a value, so why is that surprising? Where did you expect the articles to be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.articles` does not exist in you class as a property. You can simply add

```js
this.articles = [ { id: 1, title: "Article 1" }, { id: 2, title: "Article 2" } ];
```

after your `console.log()` statement in the constrcutor.